# binding datatable columns to class property stored in a list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Sorry for the confusing title.  I have a dynamically generated grid bound to a datatable.  When a column is clicked, I create a new class that stores information required for filtering (distinct list of items, column index, header color, etc.  I store these in a List.  I have a template header column that creates a label and button in a stackpanel on top of the header.  I use the codebehind to grab the column index and set a properties in the view model.

Everything is working great, except I am not quite sure how to bind the label's background color to the List where the columnIndex property = the actual column index.  I know that's probably still fairly confusing, here's code:

Xaml template column:

```
<local:UserControlViewBase.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="150">
                            <Label Width="90" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}},Path=Column.Header}"
                                Padding="12,0,12,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            <Button Content="Ok" Padding="12,0,12,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</local:UserControlViewBase.Resources>
```

Code Behind (Xaml.cs file):

```
private void TestListView_MouseUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GenericQueueViewModel temp = (GenericQueueViewModel)this.DataContext;
        DataGridColumnHeader oTest;
        Button oBtn;
        int x = 0;
        if (!(e.OriginalSource.GetType() == typeof(Button)))
        {
            return;               
        }
        else
        {
            oBtn = (Button)e.OriginalSource;
            DataGrid oTst = (DataGrid)e.Source;
            DataGridColumn oCol = (DataGridColumn)oTst.Columns.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Header == oBtn.DataContext);
            int index = oTst.Columns.IndexOf(oCol);

            DataGridColumnHeader colHeader = GetHeader(oCol, oTst);


            double newX = temp.OldScrollValue;               
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            {
                newX += oTst.Columns[i].ActualWidth;
            }

            Thickness oThick = new Thickness(newX, -122, 0, 0);
            temp.FilterWindowMargin = oThick;
            x = (sender as DataGrid).Columns.IndexOf(oCol);
            colHeader.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightSkyBlue;
        }

        temp.UpdateFilterList(x);
    }
```

ViewModel Class:

```
[SerializableAttribute]
    public class FilterList
    {
        private int _columnIndex;

        public int ColumnIndex
        {
            get { return _columnIndex; }
            set 
            { 
                _columnIndex = value;
            }
        }

        private System.Windows.Media.Brush _headerColor;

        public System.Windows.Media.Brush HeaderColor
        {
            get { return _headerColor; }
            set 
            { 
                _headerColor = value; 
            }
        }


        private Nullable<bool> _selectAll;

        public Nullable<bool> SelectAll
        {
            get { return _selectAll; }
            set 
            { 
                _selectAll = value; 
            }
        }


        private List<CheckedListItem<DistinctColumnData>> _filterItems;

        public List<CheckedListItem<DistinctColumnData>> FilterItems
        {
            get { return _filterItems; }
            set 
            {
                LastFilterItems = _filterItems;
                _filterItems = value;
            }
        }

        private List<CheckedListItem<DistinctColumnData>> _viewableFilterItems;

        public List<CheckedListItem<DistinctColumnData>> ViewableFilterItems
        {
            get { return _viewableFilterItems; }
            set 
            { 
                _viewableFilterItems = value; 
            }
        }


        private List<CheckedListItem<DistinctColumnData>> _lastFilterItems;

        public List<CheckedListItem<DistinctColumnData>> LastFilterItems
        {
            get { return _lastFilterItems; }
            set { _lastFilterItems = value; }
        }

        private bool _isFiltered;

        public bool IsFiltered
        {
            get { return _isFiltered; }
            set 
            { 
                _isFiltered = value; 
            }
        }


        private bool _isFilterable;

        public bool IsFilterable
        {
            get { return _isFilterable; }

            set 
            { 
                _isFilterable = value; 
            }
        }


        public FilterList()
            : this(-1) { }

        public FilterList(int columnIndex)
            : this(columnIndex, new List<CheckedListItem<DistinctColumnData>>()) { }

        public FilterList(List<CheckedListItem<DistinctColumnData>> filterList)
            : this(-1, filterList) { }

        public FilterList(int columnIndex, List<CheckedListItem<DistinctColumnData>> filterList)
            : this(columnIndex, filterList, false) { }

        public FilterList(int columnIndex, List<CheckedListItem<DistinctColumnData>> filterList, bool isFilterable)
        {
            FilterItems = filterList;
            ColumnIndex = columnIndex;
            IsFilterable = isFilterable;
            HeaderColor = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent;
        }
    }
```

ViewModel List:

```
private List<FilterList> _filterColumns;

    public List<FilterList> FilterColumns
    {
        get { return _filterColumns; }
        set 
        { 
            _filterColumns = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => FilterColumns);
        }
    }
```

So basically, I need to bind the xaml DataGridColumnHeader template Label background somehow to the FilterList in the List where the FilterList.columnIndex = DataGrid column that was clicked.  The line of code in the codebehind (xaml.cs):

```
DataGridColumnHeader colHeader = GetHeader(oCol, oTst);
```

does get a header object (GetHeader is a method I found in a different post here).  But it doesn't seem to actually do anything.  If I get the header from column0, and set it's color to LightBlue, and then click on column0 again, the header.background = null...  Even though when I step through it it does change to a hex value.. The next time it grabs the header, background = null again...

This is a generic table that needs to be able to bind to any table sent in, with any number of columns/rows, and offer filtering functionality.  The filter functionality is already working, I just can't figure out how to change the background color of the header (technically, the label on top of the header) so that they can visually see what columns are filtered.

Comment: So I have discovered how to get the label background to change, I set the main stackpanel background as such.  It works with a 0 index, when I filter column0.  However, it is changing all columns (as expected.. it's a template).  I need to know how to have it dynamically attach the column index to the column.  This is also not checking the columnIndex property in the List<FilterList>. Background="{Binding DataContext.FilterColumns[0].HeaderColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type local:UserControlViewBase}},Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

Comment: Slight correction.  It looks like the header color is changing, but it's not visible under the Stackpanel, even with Background = "Transparent" ... Not sure why.  When I click on the button, the header turns blue, and the button disappears.  When I close the filter window, the button comes back and the color is lost.  I removed the label, and gave the button a margin= 125,0,0,0 so that it forces the column width, but still can't see the header color...

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.  Have to use a converter.  Altered code as follows, adding the converter:

```
<local:UserControlViewBase.Resources>
    <Converters:BGConverter x:Key="BackgroundConverter"/>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="150">
                        <StackPanel x:Name="testtest" Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Reference TestListView}}">                                        
                            <Label Width="90" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}},Path=Column.Header}"
                                Padding="12,0,12,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            <Button Content="Ok" Padding="12,0,12,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>        
</local:UserControlViewBase.Resources>
```

Now, from the converter, I can add logic.  This uses a Singleton, so if you're not a fan, you'll need to find another way to grab your VM.  It passes the VM into the converter the first few times, so I'm storing it in my mainviewmodel, and then using it once it starts passing in columns:

```
 public class BGConverter : IValueConverter
{
     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        GenericQueueViewModel oQueue;
        System.Windows.Media.Brush returnBrush;

        DataGrid oGrid = (DataGrid)parameter;
        if (value == null)
        {
            returnBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent;
        }
        else if (oGrid == null)
        {
            returnBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent;
        }
        else if (value.GetType() == typeof(GenericQueueViewModel))
        {
            MainViewModel.Instance.GenericVM = (GenericQueueViewModel)value;
            returnBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent;
        }

        else
        {
            oQueue = MainViewModel.Instance.GenericVM;
            DataGridColumn oCol = oGrid.Columns.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Header == value);
            int colIndex = oGrid.Columns.IndexOf(oCol);
            string colName = (string)value;

            var fList = oQueue.FilterColumns.FirstOrDefault(y => y.ColumnIndex == colIndex && y.IsFiltered == true);
            if (fList == null)
            {
                returnBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent;
            }
            else
            {
                returnBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
            }
        }

        return returnBrush;
    }
}
```